# How to get column with duplicate record with PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called `blog`

| blog id | title | author_name | author 2 | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iot1 | sha | dd | 2020 |
| 2 | iot2 | sha | alif | 2020 |
| 3 | iot3 | mia | alif | 2020 |
| 4 | man1 | sha | lia | 2020 |

I do search bar using `%$keyword%` And if `iot` is input in the search bar for example, I want to display result like:

```
sha  iot1,iot2,man
mia  iot3
alif iot2,iot3
```

where display `author_name` that belongs to the title that match keyword and display author2 that have more than 1 record that match keyword.

My current attempt result is:

```
sha,mia,dd
iot1,iot2,iot3
```

My code:

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    author_name)grouped_author_name,author2, GROUP_CONCAT(title)grouped_title , count(*) cnt 
    FROM `blog` 
    WHERE `title` LIKE '%$keyword%' AND year>='2019' GROUP BY author2 >1
```

Comment: `author_name`  and `author2` strike me as bad database design if you want to group by two columns as if they were one column.  You should be using a prepared statement for security/stability.  For faster and easier to verify responses from volunteers, I recommend making a db-fiddle to share in your question body.  We should never see `or die(mysqli_error())` in production code.  Are you considering a UNION?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Union` and `Subquery` and `Group_concat` to get your desired result

Your data

```
drop 
  table if exists tmp_a;
create table tmp_a (
  blog_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
  author_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
  author2 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
  year year
);
INSERT INTO tmp_a(
  blog_id, title, author_name, author2, 
  year
) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'iot1', 'sha', 'dd', '2020'), 
  (2, 'iot2', 'sha', 'alif', '2020'), 
  (3, 'iot3', 'mia', 'alif', '2020'), 
  (4, 'man1', 'sha', 'lia', '2020');
```

your query

```
SELECT author_name,
       Group_concat(title) title,
       Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT blog_id,
               title,
               author_name,
               year
        FROM   tmp_a
        UNION
        SELECT blog_id,
               title,
               author2 AS author_name,
               year
        FROM   tmp_a) t2
--WHERE  author_name LIKE '%keyword%'  --where condition 
---       AND year >= '2019' --where condition 
GROUP  BY author_name
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```